# Term for book glorifying villain

Tags: word-choice

Is there a specific term which can be used for books glorifying evil or the villain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to go *too* dark, you may be thinking of a *picaresque* novel:

> **picaresque** of or relating to an episodic style of fiction dealing with the adventures of a rough and dishonest but appealing hero

[Google definition]

The picaresque hero is dishonest and may be somewhat villainous, but has interesting adventures and enough redeeming qualities that readers can enjoy the tale without being too appalled.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends largely on your intent in referring to the book, or on the writer's intent.

If you want to emphasize the way a book disregards or exists in conflict with common morality, then a convenient and effective phrase description is "transgressive" or "an example of Transgressive Literature".

If you want to emphasize the role of the main character as an Anti-hero, then the terms "anti-heroic" or "morally ambiguous" are serviceable (but not elegant).

If you want to emphasize that a book as an attempt to change our perception of a character or action as villainous then you might say "subversive" or "an Apologia". Usually these would be applied in non-fiction contexts.

Without further understanding the intent of usage, it's impossible to narrow it down further, so here are a few other candidates: 
Malevolent, Malicious, Misanthropic, Amoral, Immoral, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean **[antihero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihero)**. Not really a villain but a character who is unconventional and veers away from the traditional blueprint of a *hero*

> The antihero or antiheroine is a leading character in a film, book or
>   play who lacks some or all of the traditional heroic qualities, such
>   as altruism, idealism, courage, nobility, fortitude, and moral
>   goodness. ...

Otherwise the [Villian Protagonist](http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/47408.Villain_Protagonist)

> The difference between an anti-hero and a villain protagonist is that
>   the anti-hero often has the role of a hero but with darker sides.
>
> This list is meant to help list books with characters that have the
>   role of what would normally be considered an antagonist, someone you
>   normally wouldn't cheer for. Maybe they have sympathetic sides, maybe
>   they don't but the important thing is that **it's the main character of
>   the story.**

[Examples of Villain Protagonists](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Protagonist_Villain) are (including video game villains): 
Beetlejuice; Darth Vader; Slender Man; Sasuke Uchiha; Hannibal Lecter; Carrie White; Godzilla; Chucky; Venom (Marvel); Bowser...

Comment: ... which might describe the main character, but the question is how would you describe the book?

Comment: @RoaringFish and that is why I said "I think you mean" at the beginning. A story is a story, if it's an adventure book with a villain as its protagonist, it's still an adventure book. The same for a science-fiction novel, a thriller, a romance, a horror, graphic novel etc.

Comment: Indeed, but if you say "I think you mean..." then you are answering your own question, the one you think the OP should have asked, rather than the queston he actually did ask: "Is there a specific term which can be used for *books* glorifying evil or the villain?" What he is looking for is something like 'dystopian' but specifically for glorifying evil.

Comment: @RoaringFish  Ahh valid point. I won't defend my answer beyond this point. Dystopian, good word, wish I had thought of that.